# Siebel Tools can't scroll when editing applet web layout?

Tags: siebel

I've replaced my old dev laptop with a new one, and my Siebel 7.8 Tools aren't enjoying the change: the applet web layout editor gets frozen when I try to scroll.

The applet loads fine, I can add controls, move them around or remove them... but if I try to scroll, it only does so for a moment and then it gets frozen: everything inside the web layout pane (including the scrollbars) stops responding. I've also noticed a visual glitch when it happens - half of the "InfoButton" placeholder and half of the "Elemento" field are duplicated:

[image: Screenshot]

The rest of the Siebel Tools keep working however, I can just close the layout editor and open a new one, which will work without problem... until I try to scroll again.

It happens also if I try to show a bigger applet area without using the scrollbar (for example, if I hide the object explorer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to have more room), or if I click on `Preview`. Only in that case, instead of a glitched layout, it shows all blank (and freezes).

It doesn't matter if it's a list applet or a form one; whether I'm connected to my local DBF database or to the server repository; if I run the Siebel Tools with or without administrative privileges...

To make things even weirder, the first time I edited an applet web layout in the new computer, it worked fine (a lot of scrolling included). The issue started with the second applet I tried to edit (but now it happens with *the good applet* too).

The new computer is running Windows 7 (64bits) with IE8. The old computer had exactly the same, only the 32bits version. Siebel Tools have been properly installed (I didn't just transfer my old folder to the new PC). And I've checked the tools.cfg file, specifically the `WebClientSiteDir` property, which points to the right folder, `C:\Siebel_7.8\Tools\PUBLIC\ENU`.

Any ideas, other than reinstall the Tools? Has it happened to anyone before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I tried *a lot* of different things, including a full reinstall of Siebel Tools. In the end, it was much easier to fix: I just needed to enable the option "**Run this program in Windows XP compatibility mode**", in the Tools shortcut.

I'd swear I didn't have it enabled in my previous computer and it worked just fine, but anyway... that fixed the issue for me.